# H265 - a codec only for powerfull computers?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, vlc, codec

I have converted a video of mine with ffmpeg into H265 codec. Great: Much smaller at the same quality. But then I noticed the video is blocky. I thought there was an error during re-coding. But no: I noticed that it gets blocky if I run other programs than VLC. I looked at how much of the CPU is required: 16% with the old codec, 60% with H265. So: Is H265 too demanding for me, since my computer (from 2013) is too weak?

Comment: this isn't a unix question. but hardware decoding is a powerful thing, and it isn't going to exist in hardware older than the format

Comment: @Fox:Ok, should I rather ask at superusers? Also: I am not sure I understand what you mean: I can display the H265-videos, but they just eat a lot of CPU power. What is hardware decoding? Is it that H265 is decoded closer to the hardware and because my computer is too old, so it might not have it and needs to do it all in software, which is expensive?

Comment: *So: Is H265 too demanding for me, since my computer (from 2013) is too weak?* Yes, it is. If you specified your CPU it would be easier to answer. Also read this: https://switchboard.live/blog/video-encoder-options-hardware-vs-software https://restream.io/blog/hardware-encoding-vs-software-encoding/ https://www.macxdvd.com/mac-video-converter-pro/hardware-decoding-4k-ultra-hd-video.htm

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: Which command returns the information that is useful for this question?

Comment: @Make42 yes, software decoding is going to use CPU time to compute what the hardware would if it were available. but since H.265 hardware decoding didn't exist when your computer was built, you're stuck with that